# Python sqlalchemy telegram bot

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, telegram-bot

I use `sqlalchemy` and sometimes i have this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed

I think this is a problem with session but I do not know how to fix it

Code:

```
engine = create_engine(config['engine'])
connection = engine.connect()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = None

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config['telegram_token'])
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/tg', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        global session
        session = Session()
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id == config['chat_id'], content_types=['text'])
def chat_handler(message):
    tg_id = message.from_user.id
    in_db = session.query(ChatMessage).filter(
        ChatMessage.message_id == message.message_id).count()
    if in_db == 0:
        die_time = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0) + \
            timedelta(seconds=config['chat_message_lifetime'])
        if message.pinned_message != None:
            die_time = None
        chat_mess = ChatMessage(
            user_id=None, advorder_id=None, message_id=message.message_id, dietime=die_time)
        session.add(chat_mess)
        session.commit()


bot.remove_webhook()
bot.set_webhook(url=config['webhook_url_base'],
                certificate=open(config['webhook_ssl_cert'], 'r'))
app.run()
```

Comment: Your session is global. Depending on your setup this may cause troubles if two requests will be processed simultaneously. The safer practice would be one session per logical operation/request.